# Extract / copy part of map and use as image. – Can this be done using PHP?

Tags: php, jquery

If i open google map on browser and I want to crop a part of map and want to use as an image. 
Can it be done using PHP or jQuery?

Comment: did you get anything for this ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes it can be done (technically) but it is against the TOS of Google (don't nail me on the last point, clarify that with the google deparment first).